# Refactoring UPDATE CASE Statements for Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

Is it possible to optimize these queries in terms of performance:

```
UPDATE PEOPLE  
SET ID_STATE =  CASE  
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 2 THEN 9 
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 3 THEN 9 
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 7 THEN 8
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 8 THEN 9
                        ELSE 0
                    END 
WHERE ID_STATE IN (2,3,7,8)
GO
UPDATE PEOPLE  
SET ID_PRESI =  CASE  
                    WHEN ID_PRESI = 3 THEN NULL 
                    WHEN ID_PRESI = 4 THEN NULL 
                    ELSE 0
                END 
WHERE ID_PRESI IN (3,4)
GO
UPDATE STATE_FIC_STATE_PEOPLE  
SET ID_STATE =  CASE  
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 2 THEN 9 
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 3 THEN 9 
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 7 THEN 8
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 8 THEN 9
                        ELSE 0
                    END 
WHERE ID_STATE IN (2,3,7,8)
GO
UPDATE STATE_PEOPLE_PRECIS  
SET ID_STATE =  CASE  
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 2 THEN 9 
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 3 THEN 9 
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 7 THEN 8
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 8 THEN 9
                        ELSE 0
                    END 
WHERE ID_STATE IN (2,3,7,8)
GO
UPDATE STATE_PEOPLE_PRECIS  
SET ID_PRESI =  CASE  
                    WHEN ID_PRESI = 3 THEN NULL 
                    WHEN ID_PRESI = 4 THEN NULL 
                    ELSE 0
                END 
WHERE ID_PRESI IN (3,4)
GO
```

Comment: Hi @mercer, you can start by using a `IN` -> `WHEN ID_STATE IN (2,3,8) THEN 9`

Comment: If "optimize" is supposed to mean "faster" here, I think there is no way to optimize these statements.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i edit my tittle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got some redundant code in there;

In this bit, your only options are the 4 values in your where clause, the only one that's different is 7 (returns an 8), everything else returns a 9;

```
UPDATE PEOPLE  
SET ID_STATE =  CASE  
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 7 THEN 8 
                        ELSE 9
                    END 
WHERE ID_STATE IN (2,3,7,8)
GO
```

You want anything with a 3 or 4 set to NULL, your where clause will do this. There's no need for the CASE statement;

```
UPDATE PEOPLE  
SET ID_PRESI =  NULL
WHERE ID_PRESI IN (3,4)
GO
```

These next two are the same as the first one;

```
UPDATE STATE_FIC_STATE_PEOPLE  
SET ID_STATE =  CASE  
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 7 THEN 8 
                        ELSE 9
                    END 
WHERE ID_STATE IN (2,3,7,8)
GO

UPDATE STATE_PEOPLE_PRECIS  
SET ID_STATE =  CASE  
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 7 THEN 8 
                        ELSE 9
                    END 
WHERE ID_STATE IN (2,3,7,8)
GO
```

I've edited slightly from the original answer, the case statements only need to return 8 if ID_STATE = 7, otherwise it's a 9.

Answer (score 5):

I would go the same as Rich Benner as you have much redundancy here

```
UPDATE PEOPLE  
SET ID_STATE =  CASE  
                        WHEN ID_STATE IN (2,3,8) THEN 9 
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 7 THEN 8
                        ELSE 0
                    END, 
    ID_PRESI =  CASE  
                    WHEN ID_PRESI IN (3,4) THEN NULL 
                    ELSE 0
                END                         
GO

UPDATE STATE_FIC_STATE_PEOPLE  
SET ID_STATE =  CASE  
                        WHEN ID_STATE IN (2,3,8) THEN 9 
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 7 THEN 8
                        ELSE 0
                    END 
GO

UPDATE STATE_PEOPLE_PRECIS  
SET ID_STATE =  CASE  
                        WHEN ID_STATE IN (2,3,8) THEN 9  
                        WHEN ID_STATE = 7 THEN 8
                        ELSE 0
                    END, 
    ID_PRESI =  CASE  
                    WHEN ID_PRESI IN (3,4) THEN NULL  
                    ELSE 0
                END 

GO
```

Comment: one thing is I go on the premise that your db is not that big. If it is large db, then adding a where clause can be a smart move

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have two kinds of update queries. For the shorter kind there's an easy optimization, since there's actually no need for the CASE (all entries that match the WHERE are set to NULL). So that can be changed to:

```
SET ID_PRESI =  NULL
WHERE ID_PRESI IN (3,4)
```

The other updates can be optimized a bit also by getting rid of the CASE:

```
SET ID_STATE = IF(ID_STATE = 7, 8, 9)
WHERE ID_STATE IN (2,3,7,8)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun ;)

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = (
SELECT REPLACE(
'
    UPDATE {0}
    SET ID_STATE =
            CASE
                WHEN ID_STATE IN (2, 3, 8) THEN 9
                WHEN ID_STATE = 7 THEN 8
                ELSE 0
            END
        ' + CASE WHEN ex = 1 THEN ', ID_PRESI =
            CASE
                WHEN ID_PRESI IN (3, 4) THEN NULL
                ELSE 0
            END
            ' ELSE '' END
            , '{0}', tbl)
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ('PEOPLE', 1),
            ('STATE_FIC_STATE_PEOPLE', 0),
            ('STATE_PEOPLE_PRECIS', 1)
    ) t (tbl, ex)
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')

PRINT @SQL
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE
    PEOPLE  
SET
    ID_STATE =  CASE
                    WHEN ID_STATE = 2 THEN 9 
                    WHEN ID_STATE = 3 THEN 9 
                    WHEN ID_STATE = 7 THEN 8
                    WHEN ID_STATE = 8 THEN 9
                    ELSE 0 -- Option 1
                    ELSE ID_STATE -- Option 2
                END,
    ID_PRESI =  CASE  
                    WHEN ID_PRESI = 3 THEN NULL 
                    WHEN ID_PRESI = 4 THEN NULL 
                    ELSE 0 -- Option 1
                    ELSE ID_PRESI -- Option 2
                END;
GO

UPDATE
    STATE_FIC_STATE_PEOPLE  
SET
    ID_STATE =  CASE  
                    WHEN ID_STATE = 2 THEN 9 
                    WHEN ID_STATE = 3 THEN 9 
                    WHEN ID_STATE = 7 THEN 8
                    WHEN ID_STATE = 8 THEN 9
                    ELSE 0 -- Option 1
                    ELSE ID_STATE -- Option 2
                END;
GO

UPDATE
    STATE_PEOPLE_PRECIS  
SET
    ID_STATE =  CASE  
                    WHEN ID_STATE = 2 THEN 9 
                    WHEN ID_STATE = 3 THEN 9 
                    WHEN ID_STATE = 7 THEN 8
                    WHEN ID_STATE = 8 THEN 9
                    ELSE 0 -- Option 1
                    ELSE ID_STATE -- Option 2
                END,
    ID_PRESI =  CASE  
                    WHEN ID_PRESI = 3 THEN NULL 
                    WHEN ID_PRESI = 4 THEN NULL 
                    ELSE 0 -- Option 1
                    ELSE ID_PRESI -- Option 2
                END;
GO
```

Comment: No, by ommiting the WHERE clauses you are suddenly updating all records in the tables, which is slower and obviously undesired.

Comment: 1 scan is possibly faster than 2 separate seeks. If the where clause is actually required, then option 2 will work.